# Solving problem using related rates yields incorrect result

Tags: calculus, related-rates

I've been trying for a while to figure out what I did wrong on this problem, help would be appreciated.

"A 25-ft ladder is leaning against a wall. If we push the
ladder toward the wall at a rate of 1 ft/sec, and the bottom
of the ladder is initially 20 ft away from the wall, how
fast does the ladder move up the wall 5 sec after we start
pushing?"

$x$ = distance from wall, $y$ = height of ladder on wall, $h$ = length of ladder
$$\frac {dx}{dt} = -1, t = 5$$
$$x^2 + y^2 = h^2$$
$$x^2 +y^2 = 25^2$$
$$2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{-x\frac{dx}{dt}}{y}$$
Since the ladder is moving toward the wall at 1 ft/sec for 5 sec, $x(t = 5) =20-5 = 15$

$$y(t=5) = \sqrt{25^2 - 15^2}=20$$
Substitute variables in equation:
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{-(15)(-1)}{20}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{3}{4}$$
The issue is that if $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{3}{4},$ the ladder would have risen 3.75 ft. in 5 seconds instead of 5 feet it SHOULD have risen, which is given by:
$$\Delta y = y(t=5) - y(t=0)$$
$$(\sqrt{25^2 - 15^2}) - (\sqrt{25^2 - 20^2})$$
$$15-20$$
$$5$$
Thank you for reading and any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start you have $y(0)=\sqrt {25^2-20^2}=15$.  You are correct that the top has risen $5$ feet in $5$ seconds, but that does not mean that it has risen steadily at $1$ ft/sec for the whole time.  Because $\frac {dx}{dt}=-1$ you found $$\frac {dy}{dt}=\frac xy$$
At $t=0$ that means that $\frac {dy}{dt}=\frac {20}{15}=\frac 43$ and at $t=5$ that means $\frac {dy}{dt}=\frac {15}{20}=\frac 34$.  There is no contradiction here.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that the rate of change had to be constant for some reason. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your notation, you have that
$$
x(t) = 20 - t, \quad y(t)=\sqrt{25^2-x(t)^2},
$$

and so,
$$
y'(t) = \frac{-2 x'(t)x(t)}{2 \sqrt{25^2-x(t)^2}},
$$

which means that
$$
y'(5)=\frac{15}{\sqrt{25^2-15^2}}=\frac{3}{4}
$$

which was in fact your answer.

The vertical displacement does not have to match the horizontal one. They are just connected through the expression $x(t)^2 + y(t)^2=25^2$.